# After updating to Target API 26 few phone are not supported any more

Tags: android, android-api-levels

After updating to TARGET API 26 few device (Mainly Sony Xperia eg. **Xperia XA F3115**) showing this error :

> Doesn't support framework version 
>   26 and onwards

How can I support this device?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="net.some.thing">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- [END gcm_permission] -->
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon">

    <activity android:name=".ui.WebViewActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: add your androidmanifest file .

Comment: what need to add @ManoharReddy

Comment: add the contents of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to your question so we can see what's wrong

Comment: @ManoharReddy updated manifest.

Comment: Just to add some reference the screen I added it's from playstore -> DeviceCatalog

Comment: *How can I support this device?* you can not. Btw your targetSdk level is 3 years old. Set it to 29.

Comment: @Anirban were you able to figure that out? I am facing kinda similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was don't have a camera features because of that it was not supported. Because my app using an SDK which has an camera new feature.